# How to join two tables to get the count on a where query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

Table 1: `ppl`

```
Cust No.|    sex
--------| -------
10      | M
13      | F
12      | M
19      | F
20      | M
22      | M
34      | F
```

Table 2: `hobbies`

```
Cust No. |  Hobby
---------| ---------
10       | Movies
10       | Hiking
10       | Programming
12       | Biking
12       | Movies
12       | Reading
19       | Biking
20       | Reading
22       | Movies
34       | Flying
22       | Biking
```

I am trying to **find** a distribution of most popular hobbies by Male / Female in `DESC` order from the table tables.

I have written the query to find the most popular hobbies in `DESC` order

```
select Hobby, count(*)
from hobbies
group by Hobby
```

**Question**

How can I join this with `ppl` table and then get a distribution by M/F for each one?

Note that I would like the most popular hobbies to be in DESC order. First I need most popular hobbies and then the breakdown of them in M/F

The result based on the above set up would be:

```
Hobby        |  M   | F
-------------| -----|----
Movies       | 3    | 0
Hiking       | 1    | 0
Programing   | 1    | 0
Biking       | 2    | 1
Reading      | 2    | 0
Flying       | 0    | 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a conditional aggregation query with a `join`:

```
select h.Hobby,
       sum(case when gender = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as females,
       sum(case when gender = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) as males
from hobbies h join
     people p
     on h.custno = p.custno
group by h.Hobby
order by count(*) desc;
```

Comment: How/Where would I add an `ORDER by` in that in order to get the hobbies in DESCending order (irrespective of M/F)? M/F distribution would happen AFTER I get the hobbies in `DESC` order

Comment: If I put the `order by h.Hobby DESC` then the order is NOT by the most popular hobies it seems. I would like the most popular hobbies first and then do a distribution on M/F

Comment: @Anthony . . . You would just add an `ORDER BY` as I just did.  I would note that is not how your desired result set shows up, though.

Comment: And why would a correct answer be attracting downvotes?

Comment: I worked through the problem and your answer is correct just not in the format he wanted. Still no reason to down vote.